# How to pass value to JsonPath for Gatling

Tags: scala, gatling

I want to pass `categoryId` to the jsonPath but could not find the correct way. The following is use but it doesn't accept the `$` at the beginning.

The variable is available within the object

```
object CoreRequests {
  val categoryId = Config.categoryId
```

```
.check(jsonPath(s"$..Contents[?(@.CategoryID == $categoryId)].ID").findAll.saveAs("staticMovieIDList"))
```

triple quotes also not working

```
s"""$..Contents[?(@.CategoryID == $categoryId)].ID"""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `$` is a reserved character in Scala's String interpolation, it has to be escaped (doubled).

```scala
.check(jsonPath(s"$$..Contents[?(@.CategoryID == $categoryId)].ID").findAll.saveAs("staticMovieIDList"))
```

Comment: syntactically correct but it was not working let me try again

Comment: gives this error: `Check extractor resolution crashed: No attribute named 'categoryId' is defined`

Comment: "Assuming categoryId is stored in the Session" => it's not. Where does categoryId come from? Please update your code sample.

Comment: it is available in the object, updated question

Comment: got it, updating my answer